# homepage redirects to login page when user session expires

Tags: redirect, authentication, session

**WordPress 5.9** Users trying to access the homepage when the `session expires`, are sent to `re-authenticate`.

The behavior seems weird since it only applies to the **homepage**. Users with expired sessions can access all other pages without being asked to re-authenticate.

Why is the behavior inconsistent, and how can users with expired sessions not be redirected to re-authenticate?

Comment: WP 7.x is not out yet. Have you tried changing your theme and deactivating plugins to see if one of them is the culprit?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! I have made already an amendment to match the latest version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you looked at your plugins one by one and none of them causes the problem, look at your template files that display your home page – could be `index.php, home.php, content.php, content-{slug/id}.php or page-templates/...`, depending on your theme and settings.

Look for

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

or anything that seems to resemble this. It could be a shortcode or hook also, but its name will probably have something to do with user/login/auth.
If you found it, comment it out and reload, and see if it's fixed.

Comment: thanks a ton! problem solved! I've added also a safeguard on the .htaccess to redirect users to properly log out so it does not reoccur after update